# Approved a Synapse Private Managed End for DFS

Tags: azure-synapse, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cli

I have a Terraform script that creates a Synapse Managed Private End Points (PEP).

The PEPs are getting created in Synapse via Terraform but for the 'dfs' (Az storage account - datalake) the Terraform code (executing Powershell) that carries out an PEP approval does not seem to work. I have put debug and run the script and its seeing the PEP as Pending and running 'az network private-endpoint-connection approve' but this is not reflecting as approved in the Azure Portal and Synapse.

```
$text = $(az network private-endpoint-connection list --id "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/isl-lds-ABC-solution-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXXXXXXdatalakesa")    
          $json = $text | ConvertFrom-Json

          foreach($connection in $json)
          {   
            $privateEndpointConnectionId = $connection.id    
            $privateEndpointId = $connection.properties.privateEndpoint.id    
            $status = $connection.properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status 

            Write-Host '*********************'
            Write-Host 'Current Status:'

            Write-Host 'privateEndpointConnectionId:'
            Write-Host $privateEndpointConnectionId
            
            Write-Host 'privateEndpointId:'
        Write-Host $privateEndpointId
            Write-Host $status       

            if($status -eq "Pending"){
              Write-Host ''
              Write-Host 'About to Approve:'
              Write-Host $privateEndpointConnectionId
              Write-Host $status
              az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id $privateEndpointConnectionId --description "Approved in Terraform"
            }
          };
```

[image]

Comment: So when I ran the code attached in my first post from the Azure Portal PowerShell interface it worked....

Comment: Ran the Terrsaform in a different environment via the Azure devOps pipeline and it worked for all the 'Synapsed Managed PEP'...

Answer (score 1):

> Approved a Synapse Private Managed End for DFS
> 'az network private-endpoint-connection approve' but this is not reflecting as approved in the Azure Portal and Synapse

It seems there might be an issue with the `endpointid` command syntax within Terraforms provisioner.

For approving the `private-endpoint-connection` state using `PowerShell` in Terraform, you can use the following command to store the value in a variable.

```
endpointid=$(az network private-endpoint-connection list --id "${azurerm_storage_account.example.id}" --query "[?properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status=='Pending'].id" -o tsv)
```

Here is updated code to create private-endpoint and approving the connection.

```kotlin
provider "azurerm"{
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "synapse-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
  lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = all 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "synapse1-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = all 
  }
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "service" {
  name                 = "service"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = all 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "demosynapsetest"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = "true"
  lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = all 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data_lake_g2fs" {
  name               =  "demostorage"
  storage_account_id =  azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = all 
  }
}

   
# create azure synapse
resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "synapse" {
  name                            = "samplesynapse"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.data_lake_g2fs.id
  managed_resource_group_name     = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}-syn-managed"
  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
  public_network_access_enabled   = false
  data_exfiltration_protection_enabled = true
  sql_administrator_login              = "Venkatsql"
  sql_administrator_login_password     = "Welcome@123$"
      identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }  
}


resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "demoendpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.service.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "sample-connection"
    is_manual_connection           = true
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
    request_message                   = "Approval for Private Endpoint connection"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "powershell" {
  triggers = {
    dummy = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      endpointid=$(az network private-endpoint-connection list --id "${azurerm_storage_account.example.id}" --query "[?properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status=='Pending'].id" -o tsv)
      az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id "$endpointid" --description "Approved in Terraform"
    EOT
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_endpoint.example]
}
```

**Before approving**

[image]

The connection state has been **approved** after executing the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ran the Terraform (code as in original post) in a different environment via the Azure devOps pipeline and it worked for all the 'Synapsed Managed PEP'.